# How do I remove a blower wheel from a shaft that uses a slip ring?

Tags: exhaust-fan

Exhaust fan blower wheel is attached to the shaft of a 1/100 hp induction motor; I can see a ring thru’ the vanes; how to remove? How do I remove a blower wheel from a shaft that uses a slip ring?

[image: Blower wheel on induction motor][image]

Comment: what is the picture supposed to show? ... why did you post it?

Comment: To show the space limiting the tools needed; maybe a Swiss Army knife has it?

Comment: the second picture would actually be useful if the important part was in focus ..... if you really need help, then you have to make more effort to provide useful information .... slide a strip of paper through the fan blades and behind the spindle, so that the camera does not focus on the background

Answer (score 2):

If you look close where the shaft and the squirrel cage or blower connect there is a thick piece of metal. Rotate the blower and look for a hole there. It's usually a set screw or grub screw holding the blower to the shaft. Most of the time these are Allen screws but I have found a few that are standard slot screws, normally on the inside through the fins unless a larger blower then sometimes on the outside. Or that is what I have found in the past.

Answer (score 1):

On my Nutone fan it is just pressed on, no set screw or anything. I just pulled it off and when I got a new motor, I just pressed it on the new shaft. It's not like there is a lot of force involved in that fan, it's a 1/100th HP motor...

Answer (score 0):

[image: tool to use][image]

Eureka!  A letter opener I think it is, worked !  It was slim enough to slide between the vanes.   Yes it is pressed on but the ring squeezes the slotted hub and even after the ring was pried off, it took severe pounding on the axel end to break it’s clutches.